# xml Design show Completely InCorrect

Tags: java, android, xml

I supposed that I created a design on XML file but it shows in incorrect view like this
[image]
and this is my XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F7F7F7"
    tools:context="mediaclub.app.paymob.ElShoghlActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/amountTv"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="21dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amountTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Amount"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:textColor="#3cb5a4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.354" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" El shoghl"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="126dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="pending"
        android:textColor="#3cb5a4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:text="100"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EGP"
        android:textColor="#3cb5a4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView7"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:textColor="#3cb5a4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="Periodic Time"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.717"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="108dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Monthly"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="108dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:text="members"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/amountTv"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/amountTv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amountTv"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <View
        android:background="#737373"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="166dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="107dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/addicon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E93232"
        android:text="Remove"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="420dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

    <View
        android:background="#737373"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="468dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/joinedicon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.809"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Joined"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="436dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="191dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nextbtn"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="139dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mahmoud"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.09"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.801" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.592"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't know what exactly I did wrong but the view shows correctly in the xml file,sorry if any thing is not clear

and this is the right view to be supposed
[image]

Comment: you are using ConstraintLayout which need to set all constraints and it introduced recently for the complex ui, what is your requirement if it is simple strait forward you can go for linear or relative layout.

Comment: @Pavan you mean that instead using constraint layout use Relative layout?

Comment: yes if you are new with ConstraintLayout you can go for Relative layout else it is your choice.

Comment: @Pavan thanks for help but if I change to relative layout I will destroy my whole ui is there any other solution for this,I had to re create the xml file again

Comment: just replace xml root layout ConstraintLayout with RelativeLayout and make changes in properties you using to position your views

Comment: ok thanks alot @Pavan am gonna try this